# MVC Data Model from URL to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi i need to pass some data from an URL to a controller in MVC. The data are in @Value = @Request.QueryString["rt"] in this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPasswordToken", "Account")){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Reset Password non riuscito")
<div class="container above-footer login-form">
    <div class="col-md-6" align="center" style=" margin-left:25%; margin-top:100px; margin-bottom:100px;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ResetToken)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResetToken, new { @Value = @Request.QueryString["rt"] })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ResetToken)
        </div>
```

And i need to retrieve this value in the AccountController when i go on the submit button associated to this view. What is the best mode to do this without see it in the page?

I know is a very simple question but i need to do only this modification for tomorrow and i am very busy. Thanks to all and sorry for the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller action that rendered this view (the GET action):

```
model.ResetToken = Request["rt"];
return View(model);
```

and then in the view simply:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResetToken)
```

or if you don't want this to be shown in the form you could also use a hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ResetToken)
```

Now when the form is submitted back to the `ResetPasswordToken` action you can read this value from the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResetPasswordToken(MyViewModel model)
{
    // you can use the model.ResetToken property here to read the value
}
```

Alternatively you could include this value as part of the url when generating the `action` attribute of your HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPasswordToken", "Account", new { ResetToken = Request["rt"] }))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think i am not clear,sorry... I don't want the value in this view...i want to pass the value to a controller associated to a button...the button call "resetpasswordtoken"

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what I showed in my answer. The `ResetPasswordToken` action taking a view model called `MyViewModel` with a string property called `ResetToken`. So that inside your POST controller action could get the value using `model.ResetToken`.

Comment: Ah ok sorry sorry...five monutes ago my browser had visualized only the first part of your message...i don't know why!thank you very much and good holidays!